# Nouns expressing number and weight

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns, grammatical-number

I read in a grammer book that nouns expressing number and weight (when preceded by numerals ) are not pluralized, as: five dozen apples, five head of cattle, four yoke of oxen, etc.

My question is weather it is true in the case of 'liter'. I have some possible cases in mind.

> 1. Five liters of water.
> 2. Five liters water.
> 3. Five liter water.
> 4. Five-liter water.

Which of the above cases (1 to 4) are correct and which of the above cases are wrong?

Comment: Some nouns only are not pluralized. The rest are.

Comment: No reference here so not an answer, but this generally doesn't apply to _units of measure_ such as liters, pounds, miles, etc. -- those get pluralized.  You would say that you have **five liters of water**.  (You could also say that you have five thousand milliliter**s** of water)

Comment: Certain units of measure are not pluralised - dozen, hundred, thousand, (etc). Also to do with livestock - head of cattle or sheep, yoke of oxen. With game, neither the unit nor the noun is plural: five brace of partridge, pheasant, snipe, etc. Big game hunters do not pluralise animal nouns, e.g. I shot five lion, ten gazelle, three moose.

Comment: Your (3) and (4) are identical.For me, (1) is correct and (2) is so so. In US, we call Five-liter can or water bottle to show the size of the container.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the words that are singular after a number are quite old fashioned.

Words like dozen (12), score (20) and gross (144) can be used about anything, and are treated the same as numbers:

1. they are singular when preceded by a determiner or a multiplying number
2. it is not necessary to use **of** between a number and the word its refers to
3. the plural is only used for approximate numbers.

> a dozen eggs
>   five dozen eggs
>   dozens of people came to the shop today

For words that have a much more limited usage like **head** (people and cattle), **yoke** (oxen) and **brace** (game birds, but can be used for other things), only rule 1 applies.

> a yoke of oxen
>   five head of cattle
>   several brace of pheasants

The word **pair** is widely used in modern english, and this conforms to the normal rules for nouns:

> a pair of socks
>   five pairs of socks
>   several pairs of socks

For older (imperial) weights, these Ngram graphs for [pound](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20pound%20of%2Cfive%20pounds%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20pound%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20pounds%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfive%20pound%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20pounds%20of%3B%2Cc0) and [ton](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20ton%20of%2Cfive%20tons%20of%2C%20five%20tonnes%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20ton%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20tons%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20tonnes%20of%3B%2Cc0) show that these units of weight were historically used as a singular after a number, but even a hundred years ago it was a lot more common to use a plural after a number. For [stone](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20stone%20of%2Cfive%20stones%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20stone%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20stones%20of%3B%2Cc0), the singular and plural are a lot closer, but for [ounces](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20ounce%20of%2C%20five%20ounces%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20ounces%20of%3B%2Cc0), there is no evidence of usage of a singular after a number and for [hundredweight](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20hundredweight%20of%2C%20five%20hundredweights%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20hundredweight%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20hundredweights%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfive%20hundredweight%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20hundredweights%20of%3B%2Cc0) instances of the plural are in the minority.

For modern (metric) weights (gram, gramme, kilo, kilogram and tonne), all use a plural after a non-unity number, and also use **of**.

When an abbreviation is used, whether [metric (kg)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=5%20kg%20of%2C5%20kgs%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C5%20kg%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20kgs%20of%3B%2Cc0) or [imperial (lb)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=5%20lb%20of%2C5%20lbs%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C5%20lb%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C5%20lbs%20of%3B%2Cc0), the singular is more frequently used and the **of** is usually included.

To answer your specific question about litres: [Litre](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/litre) (UK)/liter(US) follows the same conventions as other metric units: it uses a plural after a non-unity number and requires **of**, so the first option is the correct version.

> 1 - Five liters of water.

You may occasionally see the second option, when the writer wishes to save space.

I think that you are unlikely to see 3 and 4, though you may see the abbreviation

> 5 l water

Comment: In British game usage, we say one, two three (etc) **brace** of **pheasant**. Animals that are hunted & killed are referred to in the singular. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals

Comment: @MichaelHarvey According to NGRAM, **brace of pheasants** is, and always has been, more common than **brace of pheasant**. Likewise for pigeons and partridges, but grouse is always grouse. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brace+of+pheasant%2Cbrace+of+pheasants&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrace%20of%20pheasant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrace%20of%20pheasants%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I didn't (and don't) learn to speak from Ngrams.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey; none of us did. Ngrams reflect the natural variation of usage  in written language. We can use it to understand the differences between the way we use language and the way other native speakers do, and to see how usage changes over time..

Comment: Is “a dozen of eggs” wrong? Or the “of” is just not necessary in it?

Comment: @ramtejaguthikonda  "a dozen *of* eggs is wrong, as would be "a hundred of dollars*.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* say

> **a** five-liter **bottle**

which is pretty massive if you think about it, but it's rare to read or say

> *5-liter water*

Instead English native speakers will say and write (see @JavaLatte's answer)

> Five litres of water

Note the hyphen which makes  five-liter or 5-liter  into a single *noun phrase*, which acts like an adjective. Compare “5 star hotel“ (never *five stars hotel*) and *five-year-old boy*, see [Google news](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22five-year-old%20boy%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNRvehTRKD8DYQsgqsclr7Lp94hKDg:1577354518153&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ2_S9h9PmAhX9wAIHHd95CowQ_AUoBHoECBYQBg&biw=1308&bih=647) for examples of usage.